# Botium dialogflow connector support for Dialogflow environments

Tags: dialogflow-es, botium-box

Since Dialogflow environments has gone GA, does Botium support/plan to support the environments feature in Dialogflow?

This feature would help testing different versions of the bot published in various environments.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of questions (feature requests) are better asked on Github (https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/issues).
This feature is already part of our backlog and will be delivered with the April release of Botium.

UPDATE:
Has been added with [this](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-dialogflow/commit/c232ac9fec6d75887fbe053a3f733a99d236339d) Github commit.